# Как правильно перебрать объект исключив одинаковые значения свойств?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему `persons_obj.indexOf` выдает ошибку?

```js
var json_server = {0: "sergey", 1: "maxim", 8: "michail", 11: "nina", 57: "maxim", 44: "olesya", 124: "dmitry", 145: "michail"};
var persons_arr = [];
var persons_obj = {};

$.each(json_server, function(key, val){
  if(persons_arr.indexOf(val) == -1) persons_arr.push(val);
});

console.log(persons_arr);

$.each(json_server, function(key, val){
  if(persons_obj.indexOf(val) == -1) persons_obj.push(val);
});

console.log(persons_obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

И как далее добавлять в конец объекта новые свойства?

Comment: `lastIndexOf()` по `Object.values()` как вариант. Ну, или обратный перебор их же, через `for` + `indexOf()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const json_server = {0: "sergey", 1: "maxim", 8: "michail", 11: "nina", 57: "maxim", 44: "olesya", 124: "dmitry", 145: "michail"}

console.log(
  [...new Set(Object.values(json_server))]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var json = {
  0: "sergey",
  1: "maxim",
  8: "michail",
  11: "nina",
  57: "maxim",
  44: "olesya",
  124: "dmitry",
  145: "michail"
}

const myFunc = json => {
  var obj = {};

  for (key in json) {
    let str = json[key];
    obj[str] = true;
  }

  return Object.keys(obj);
}

console.log(myFunc(json));
```

Comment: Ну а циклами быстрее и памяти не сожрал

Answer (score 2):

Довольно медленный способ по сравнению с циклами, но он прост в понимании.

1. инвертируем ключи и значения объекта
2. инвертируем еще раз объект из пункта 1

Фишка в том что у объекта не может быть одинаковых ключей и при первом перевороте одинаковые значения схлопнутся.

```js
var json_server = {0: "sergey", 1: "maxim", 8: "michail", 11: "nina", 57: "maxim", 44: "olesya", 124: "dmitry", 145: "michail"};

var inv = inverse(json_server);
var data = inverse(inv);
console.log(data);


function inverse (o){
  var i = {}
  Object.keys(o).forEach(k => i[o[k]] = k);
  return i;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

PS: `.indexOf(val)` метод массива, а вызываете Вы его на объекте, метод, чтобы убедится есть ли в объекте ключ `.hasOwnProperty`

И в "конец" добавлять не получится, объект не гарантирует порядок следования полей

Comment: А есть вариант конвертировать многоуровневый объект в многоуровневый массив?

Comment: @Bert наверняка да, вот только нужен пример до и после

Answer (score 1):

> Почему `persons_obj.indexOf` выдает ошибку?

Потому что у объекта `persons_obj` нет метода `indexOf`. Метода `push` у него тоже нет.

```js
var json_server = {0: "sergey", 1: "maxim", 8: "michail", 11: "nina", 57: "maxim", 44: "olesya", 124: "dmitry", 145: "michail"};
var persons_arr = [];
var persons_obj = {};

$.each(json_server, function(key, val){
  if(persons_arr.indexOf(val) == -1) persons_arr.push(val);
});

console.log(persons_arr);

$.each(json_server, function(key, val){
  if(!(val in persons_obj)) persons_obj[val] = "";
});

console.log(persons_obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```